# how does this userscript function? and how would you make it more easily read?

Tags: tampermonkey

it looks simple until you look closer into it, then it's just random.

to save space ill add the GitHub I found it at.

https://github.com/feet2/Edgenuity-Scripts/blob/main/EdgeHack.user.js

Comment: The code is obfuscated. You need to de-obfuscate it using an automatic tool or manually.

Comment: lmao i feel dumb, i never thought about it being obfuscated. yea that might be it lol thank you